# ks.test with left truncated weibull

Tags: r, distribution, weibull

The Distribution I accept my values to follow is a left truncated weibull distribution.  I do know the parameters a, shape and scale of this distribution for using the `ptrunc` command:

```
require(truncdist);

ptrunc(x,"weibull",a=a,scale=b,shape=c)
```

so I want the `ks.test` command (see below) to use the described left truncated weibull distribution instead of the "normal weibull".

```
myvalues<-c(37.5, 35.4, 27.1, 32.9, 35.9, 35.1, 34.1, 32.5, 35.5, 31.5, 38.2, 36.1,,29.9, 30.1, 34.7, 38.7 ,32.3, 38.0, 34.9, 44.2, 35.8, 30.8, 39.3, 26.0, 34.2, 40.0, 36.1 ,41.5 ,32.8, 31.9, 41.3 ,30.5, 39.9, 35.0 ,31.2 ,35.0, 30.3, 29.0, 34.4, 35.7, 34.1, 35.4); 
a<-7;
scale<-36.37516;
shape<-9.437013;
```

So I do know, that in this case it is not necessary to do the left-side truncation. But in others it will be.

```
ks.test(myvalues,"pweibull",scale=b,shape=c) #for normal weibull
```

but

```
ks.test(myvalues,ptrunc(x,"weibull",a=a,scale=b,shape=c)) # for leftruncated
```

gives a wrong result.

Comment: Could you give us an example for `myvalues`?

Comment: myvalues<-c(37.5, 35.4, 27.1, 32.9, 35.9, 35.1, 34.1, 32.5, 35.5, 31.5, 38.2, 36.1,,29.9, 30.1, 34.7, 38.7 ,32.3, 38.0, 34.9, 44.2, 35.8, 30.8, 39.3, 26.0, 34.2, 40.0, 36.1 ,41.5 ,32.8, 31.9, 41.3 ,30.5, 39.9, 35.0 ,31.2 ,35.0, 30.3, 29.0, 34.4, 35.7, 34.1, 35.4);

a<-7;scale<-36.37516;shape<-9.437013; so i do know, that in this case it ist not necessary to do the leftside truncation. but in others it is!

Comment: @paule: You should not use comments to clarify content that should be in the question body. You should also use your caps key. Expecting us to deal with your sloppiness is just unfair.

Comment: Expecting us to deal with your pervasive and unnecessary insults is strictly worse. Your first sentence said everything that needed to be said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `ptrunc` should be replaced by `rtrunc`. `ptrunc` gives a vector of probability values. But by the [documentation of](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/ks.test.html) `ks.test` we need a sample, and this is what `rtrunc` gives us. If the argument `a` of `rtrunc` is set to `-Inf`, there is no truncation and the result with `a=-Inf` is indeed the same as with `a=7`:

```
library(truncdist)

myvalues <- c(37.5, 35.4, 27.1, 32.9, 35.9, 35.1, 34.1, 32.5, 35.5, 31.5, 38.2, 36.1,29.9, 30.1, 34.7, 38.7 ,32.3, 38.0, 34.9, 44.2, 35.8, 30.8, 39.3, 26.0, 34.2, 40.0, 36.1 ,41.5 ,32.8, 31.9, 41.3 ,30.5, 39.9, 35.0 ,31.2 ,35.0, 30.3, 29.0, 34.4, 35.7, 34.1, 35.4)

a <- 7
scale<-36.37516
shape <- 9.437013

set.seed(1)
y1 <- rtrunc(myvalues,"weibull",a=-Inf,scale=scale,shape=shape)

set.seed(1)
y2 <- rtrunc(myvalues,"weibull",a=a,scale=scale,shape=shape)

set.seed(1)
ks0 <- ks.test( myvalues, "pweibull",scale=scale,shape=shape  )

set.seed(1)
ks1 <- ks.test( myvalues, y1 )

set.seed(1)
ks2 <- ks.test( myvalues, y2 )
```

.

```
> ks1

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  myvalues and y1
D = 0.21429, p-value = 0.2898
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

> ks2

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  myvalues and y2
D = 0.21429, p-value = 0.2898
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

But still the result of `ks.test( myvalues, "pweibull",scale=scale,shape=shape  )` is different:

```
> ks0

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  myvalues
D = 0.15612, p-value = 0.2576
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

The reason is that `myvalues` is too small. If we make it larger in the call of `rtrunc` (not `ks.test`), `ks0`, `ks1`, and `ks2` are almost the same:

```
library(truncdist)

myvalues <- c(37.5, 35.4, 27.1, 32.9, 35.9, 35.1, 34.1, 32.5, 35.5, 31.5, 38.2, 36.1,29.9, 30.1, 34.7, 38.7 ,32.3, 38.0, 34.9, 44.2, 35.8, 30.8, 39.3, 26.0, 34.2, 40.0, 36.1 ,41.5 ,32.8, 31.9, 41.3 ,30.5, 39.9, 35.0 ,31.2 ,35.0, 30.3, 29.0, 34.4, 35.7, 34.1, 35.4)

myManyValues <- c(outer((0:9999)/100000,myvalues,"+"))

a <- 7
scale<-36.37516
shape <- 9.437013

set.seed(1)
y1 <- rtrunc(myManyValues,"weibull",a=-Inf,scale=scale,shape=shape)

set.seed(1)
y2 <- rtrunc(myManyValues,"weibull",a=a,scale=scale,shape=shape)

set.seed(1)
ks0 <- ks.test( myvalues, "pweibull",scale=scale,shape=shape  )

set.seed(1)
ks1 <- ks.test( myvalues, y1 )

set.seed(1)
ks2 <- ks.test( myvalues, y2 )
```

.

```
> ks0

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  myvalues
D = 0.15612, p-value = 0.2576
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

> ks1

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  myvalues and y1
D = 0.15655, p-value = 0.2548
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

> ks2

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  myvalues and y2
D = 0.15655, p-value = 0.2548
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Now let's see what happens when we *do* truncate the distribution:

```
library(truncdist)

myvalues <- c(37.5, 35.4, 27.1, 32.9, 35.9, 35.1, 34.1, 32.5, 35.5, 31.5, 38.2, 36.1,29.9, 30.1, 34.7, 38.7 ,32.3, 38.0, 34.9, 44.2, 35.8, 30.8, 39.3, 26.0, 34.2, 40.0, 36.1 ,41.5 ,32.8, 31.9, 41.3 ,30.5, 39.9, 35.0 ,31.2 ,35.0, 30.3, 29.0, 34.4, 35.7, 34.1, 35.4)

myManyValues <- c(outer((0:9999)/100000,myvalues,"+"))

a <- 29
scale<-36.37516
shape <- 9.437013

set.seed(1)
y1 <- rtrunc(myManyValues,"weibull",a=-Inf,scale=scale,shape=shape)

set.seed(1)
y2 <- rtrunc(myManyValues,"weibull",a=a,scale=scale,shape=shape)

set.seed(1)
ks0 <- ks.test( myvalues, "pweibull",scale=scale,shape=shape  )

set.seed(1)
ks1 <- ks.test( myvalues, y1 )

set.seed(1)
ks2 <- ks.test( myvalues, y2 )
```

.

```
> ks0

    One-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  myvalues
D = 0.15612, p-value = 0.2576
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

> ks1

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  myvalues and y1
D = 0.15655, p-value = 0.2548
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

> ks2

    Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  myvalues and y2
D = 0.2059, p-value = 0.05683
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the `ptrunc` function incorrectly (I assume), it needs to be fed a sequence of quantiles. Below I calculate the mean and standard deviation of the Weibull based on your scale and shape parameters, then sample from 5 standard deviations above and below to produce a comparison set.

```
require(truncdist);

myvalues <- c(37.5, 35.4, 27.1, 32.9, 35.9, 35.1, 34.1, 32.5, 35.5, 31.5, 38.2, 36.1,29.9, 30.1, 34.7, 38.7 ,32.3, 38.0, 34.9, 44.2, 35.8, 30.8, 39.3, 26.0, 34.2, 40.0, 36.1 ,41.5 ,32.8, 31.9, 41.3 ,30.5, 39.9, 35.0 ,31.2 ,35.0, 30.3, 29.0, 34.4, 35.7, 34.1, 35.4); 
a <- 7;
scale <- 36.37516;
shape <- 9.437013;

# Calculate standard deviation of the weibull
weib_mean <- scale * gamma(1 + 1/shape)
weib_sd <- sqrt((scale^2) * (gamma(1 + 2/shape) - (gamma(1 + 1/shape))^2))

# Get a sample
quant <- seq(weib_mean - 5 * weib_sd, weib_mean + 5 * weib_sd, length.out = 1E5)
weibull_samp <- ptrunc(quant, "weibull", a = a, scale = scale, shape = shape)

# Take a look
plot(weibull_samp ~ quant)
```

[image]

```
# Use with test
> ks.test(sort(myvalues), weibull_samp)
       Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  sort(myvalues) and weibull_samp
D = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```